# como aumentar valor de variable

Tags: python-3.x, lista, funciones, variables, manejo-de-memoria

Buen dia, necesito ayuda. estoy diseñando una automatizacion de login, solo que tengo un problema al momento de correr la automatizacion todo va muy bien, lo que me gustaria es poder agregarle una memoria, es decir al momento de usar por ejemplo: diciembre2611-1@yahoo.com, siempre me lo tomara de esa manera. me gustaria poder usar el mismo ("diciembre2611-" +(Cambiar) +"@yahoo.com") ir cambiando el numero progresivamente acorde a las veces que se corra la automatizacion.. Me han dicho que creando un fichero pero realmente no logro hacerlo

Comment: La automatización no se ejecutaría de forma seguida en un mismo proceso, sino que cada vez que se ejecute el script debe incrementar el valor. Si es así, efectivamente necesitas persistencia en disco, un simple fichero de texto o JSON te valdría.

Comment: Entiendo, realmente recien comienzo en el mundo de la programacion , deberia usar alguna sentencia ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres que el valor se mantenga entre ejecuciones necesitas algún tipo de persistencia en disco. Desde un simple archivo de texto con estructura propia o tipo JSON, YAML, etc, pasando por metodos de serializado como Pickle o bases de datos te pueden valer.

Si solo necesitas mantener el valor de una variable entre ejecuciones locales, un archivo de texto es lo más simple y suficiente, algo como:

```
with open("config.dat", "a+") as file:
    file.seek(0)
    if data:= file.readline():
        data = int(data) + 1
    else:
        data = 1
    file.truncate(0)
    file.write(str(data))

user = f"diciembre2611-{data}@yahoo.com"
print(user)
```

En la primera ejecución tendremos `diciembre2611-1@yahoo.com`, en la segunda `diciembre2611-2@yahoo.com` y así sucesivamente hasta que modiquemos la línea del fichero o lo eliminemos.

Comment: Amigoooo muchas gracias, no se si lo dije pero recien comienzo con la programacion  y esto me ha estado costando